# How to make table search by only one column in this code

Tags: jquery

As User types in the input i am searching the table and displaying results accordingly .

Currently there are two td's in the table **Name** and **Course**

Is it Possible to make the search only for **Name** , but not Course

At present this works for both (Name and Course )

This is my code

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
        $('#searchinputtext').keyup(function()
        {
          var tr = $('#videosfromtagstable tbody tr'); //use tr not td
           if ($(this).val().length >= 2) {
                var inputdata = $.trim($("#searchinputtext").val());
                $('#errmsgnovideos').hide();
                var noElemvideo = true;
                var val = $.trim(this.value).toLowerCase();

                el = tr.filter(function()
                {
                        return this.innerHTML.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
                }); // <==== closest("tr") removed
                if (el.length >= 1)
                {
                        noElemvideo = false;
                }
                //now you fadeIn/Out every row not every cell
                tr.not(el).fadeOut();
                el.fadeIn();
                if (noElemvideo)
                        if (inputdata !== '')
                        {
                                $('#errmsgnovideos').html('No Results Matched').show();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                                $('#errmsgnovideos').hide();
                        }
                        }
                        else {
      tr.fadeIn(); //show all if length does not match the required number of characters
      $('#errmsgnovideos').hide();
    }

        })
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/30/

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you just need to change your `filter()` logic so that it only looks at the text of the first `td` within the given `tr`. To do that you can use `:eq()`, like this:

```
el = tr.filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text().toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0;
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e08o7uct/31/)